# Send handled exception reports to HockeyApp

Tags: .net, wpf, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I have a WPF app, integrated with HockeyApps, the crash report is working perfectly. Now I need to report handled crashes, I did as following but it's not sending crashes to HockeyApp dashboard:

```
try
{
   // something that crashes!
}
catch (Exception exx)
{
   // this is not working :

   ((HockeyClient)HockeyClient.Current).HandleInternalUnhandledException(exx);
   Show(exx.Message);     
}
```

Want to send catch exception details to hockey app. how to achieve that ?

Comment: He want to send handled exception in application to hockey app.